# Secondary DNS BIND server can replica partial of zones files

Tags: dns, bind9

While setting up and configuring secondary BIND9 DNS servers on Ubuntu 18.04.6 for remote locations. So far, everything seems fine, except that the secondary can copy/pull partial zones files from the master.

Is there a way to copy/pull all the zones from the primary server to the secondary server?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few zones missing in /etc/bind/named.conf.local on the secondary server. As soon as the zone(s) are added and the bind9 service is restarted, everything works as it should.